# remove item <tr> bootbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

I'm doing a ajax request to my server to remove a item and I have to remove on Front-End via bootbox, my response is ok, but I dont got remove on front-end.

```js
function Delete(data) {
       

    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Deseja Excluir o item?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn-success'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Ponto/DeleteAjuste/" + data,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                      
                            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                        
                    },
                    error: function (errormessage) {
                        alert(errormessage.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
        }
    });
```

```js
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Ajuste)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Data</td>
                    <td>@item.Descricao</td>
                    <td>@item.Horas</td>
                    
                    <td >
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-excluir" role="button" onclick="Delete(@item.Data)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Excluir</a>
                    </td>
                    
                    
                </tr>
            }
```

I think that the problem is here:
$(this).closest("tr").remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `$(this)` inside a callback will be different. In your code sample, it is the `xhr` object for the `$.ajax` call.

If you want to get the clicked element, you need to pass `this` to your js method call and store that in a variable (before your other callbacks) and use that as needed later in your `$.ajax` method's success/done callback.

So in the ui you will pass `this` as the second parameter of your `Delete` method

```
onclick="Delete(@r.Id,this)"
```

And inside the Delete method, you can store it to a local variable and you can use that later to get the closest table row.

```
function Delete(data,t)
{
    var _this = $(t);
    bootbox.confirm({
      //Your existing code goes here. Omitted to save space
    },
    callback: function(result) {
           $.ajax({
                //Your existing code goes here. Omitted to save space
                success: function(result) {
                    _this.closest("tr").remove();
           });
       }
    });
}
```

**Another option** is to use unobtrusive javascript. In this approach, you can set the url for the delete action in the anchor tag and use that instead of hard coding it in the javascript code. Also , give a css class to the a tag which can be used as the jQuery selector to wire up the `click` event.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger del-btn" 
   href="@Url.Action("DeleteAjuste","Ponto",new {id=item.Data})" 
   role="button"  ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </i> Excluir</a>
```

Now, wire up the click event on a tag with our css class. use the url attribute of the clicked a tag and use that for your ajax call. For example,

```
$(function() {

    $("a.del-btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var _this = $(this);
        var url=_this.attr("href");
        //use url for your ajax call.
        $.post(url)
         .done(function(res){
            _this.closest("tr").remove();
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to use $(this) in ajax success..

While looping, add an identifier(id or class) to your

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-excluir" id="item_{@item.id}" role="button" onclick="Delete(@item.Data)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Excluir</a>
```

Return id from the controller and you can use the same to delete the required

```
 $('#item_' + result.id).remove();
```

Hope this helps you :)